# Python TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I hit this TypeError exception recently, which I found very difficult to debug. I eventually reduced it to this small test case:

```
>>> "{:20}".format(b"hi")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

This is very non-obvious, to me anyway. The workaround for my code was to decode the byte string into unicode:

```
 >>> "{:20}".format(b"hi".decode("ascii"))
 'hi                  '
```

What is the meaning of this exception? Is there a way it can be made more clear?

Comment: Probably worth noting: this only became a `TypeError` in Python 3.4+, and it affects anything that inherits from `object` without defining `__format__` along the way (e.g. `None`; `class T(object): pass`, etc.).

Comment: For background information see https://bugs.python.org/issue7994

Comment: I had this problem too, finally found out that a variable that should have contained a float, actually contained `None`. Thus `'{0:.4f}'.format(bla)` caused this exception

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`bytes` objects do not have a `__format__` method of their own, so the default from `object` is used:

```
>>> bytes.__format__ is object.__format__
True
>>> '{:20}'.format(object())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

It just means that you cannot use anything other than straight up, unformatted unaligned formatting on these. Explicitly convert to a string object (as you did by decoding `bytes` to `str`) to get [format spec support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

You can make the conversion explicit by using the `!s` string conversion:

```
>>> '{!s:20s}'.format(b"Hi")
"b'Hi'               "
>>> '{!s:20s}'.format(object())
'<object object at 0x1100b9080>'
```

`object.__format__` explicitly rejects format strings to avoid implicit string conversions, specifically because formatting instructions are type specific.

Comment: makes sense, thanks! I wish the error were more intuitive though!

Answer (score 27):

This also happens when trying to format `None`:

```
>>> '{:.0f}'.format(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

That took a moment to work out (in my case, when `None` was being returned by an instance variable)!