# unable to get a variable into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code however, the last `"_36.0_sumoprce.txt"` is the only one getting date, none of the other ones.

```
dates = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
files_to_remove = ("{!s}_23.0_sumoocop.txt","{!s}_36.0_sumoprce.txt", "{!s}_35.0_sumoeprc.txt".format(dates, dates, dates))

print(files_to_remove)
```

What I currently see:

```
('{!s}_23.0_sumoocop.txt', '{!s}_36.0_sumoprce.txt', '20141218_35.0_sumoeprc.txt')
```

What it should print:

```
('20141218_23.0_sumoocop.txt', '20141218_36.0_sumoprce.txt', '20141218_35.0_sumoeprc.txt')
```

Any any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is no reason to do `!s` since that is the default format code.  Just use `{}`.

Comment: @iCodez: no, it is not; `!s` applies `str()` *before calling `__format__` on the object*. Try it with `'{}'.format(b'')` in Python 3, then try it again with `'{!s}'.format(b'')`.

Comment: @iCodez: the standard `object.__format__()` doesn't support formatters, for example, so `'{:20}'.format(b'')` fails, but `'{!s:20}'.format(b'')` succeeds. `object.__format__()` returns `str(self)`, but won't let you apply formatters. `'{!s:20}'.format(b'')` converts the bytes object to a string *first*, then applies the formatter.

Comment: @iCodez: see [Python TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.\_\_format\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24170567)

Comment: @iCodez: (and yes, `'{}'.format(b'')` works because there is no formatting instruction, that was my mistake).

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, I never knew that.  I always assumed `!s` was just there in case people wanted to be extra explicit.  Kudos on the detailed knowledge. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `str.format()` on *each of the strings separately*; you are not calling it on the first two strings:

```
files_to_remove = (
    "{!s}_23.0_sumoocop.txt".format(dates),
    "{!s}_36.0_sumoprce.txt".format(dates),
    "{!s}_35.0_sumoeprc.txt".format(dates)
)
```

or you can use a list compreshension:

```
files_to_remove = ("{!s}_23.0_sumoocop.txt", "{!s}_36.0_sumoprce.txt", "{!s}_35.0_sumoeprc.txt")
files_to_remove = [s.format(dates) for s in files_to_remove]
```

Note that `!s` entirely redundant here because `dates` is already a string object.