# Python : Typeerror : Non-empty format string passed to object.__format__

Tags: python, python-3.4

I know this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170519/python-typeerror-non-empty-format-string-passed-to-object-format) but the solution does not work for me. I am using `python 3.4`.

I have the following formatting in my script :

```
print ( "\t {0:20} {1:<11} {2:<25} {3:11} {4:11} {5:>32}".format( files.name.split('/')[-1], sizeof_fmt(files.size),
                                                                          str( formatted_timestamp ), files.owner,
                                                                          files.version_id, files.etag ))
```

This works in python `2.7.x`. But in `3.4` I get the error:

```
File "test.py", line 3, in file_print
      versionid, etag ))
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

I tried this:

```
print ( "\t {0:20} {1:<11} {2:<25} {3:11} {!s4:11s} {!s5:>32s}".format( files.name.split('/')[-1], sizeof_fmt(files.size),
                                                                          str( formatted_timestamp ), files.owner,
                                                                          files.version_id, files.etag ))
```

But I still get the same error. I even converted the `versionid` and `etag` to strings and end up getting the same error. Can someone explain this to me?

Etag look like this `9893532233caff98cd083a116b013c0b`, versionid is `None`

Comment: Try narrowing it down. Remove parameters one by one from the `format` call until you don't get the error anymore. Developing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the first step towards a solution.

Comment: care to explain the downvote? I have acknowledged the similar question

Comment: I didn't downvote, but others might be irritated that your code produces `NameError: name 'files' is not defined`, rather than `TypeError`. Without providing code that we can copy-paste-run, it gives the impression that you're not meeting us half way.

Comment: Conversions come *after* the field name; `{!s4:11s}` isn't valid, only `{4!s:11s}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of your parameters is a type that doesn't have their own `__format__()` method, so `object.__format__()` is used instead.

`object.__format__()` doesn't support any formatting options, including field widths and alignment, which is why you get the error.

Conversion to string first should help, but you do need to put your conversion *after* the field name; instead of `{!s4:11s}` use `{4!s:11s}`, etc:

```
print ( "\t {0:20} {1:<11} {2:<25} {3:11} {4!s:11s} {5!s:>32s}".format(
    files.name.split('/')[-1], sizeof_fmt(files.size),                                                                           
    str(formatted_timestamp), files.owner,
    files.version_id, files.etag))
```

Comment: This works. I could swear i tried having the force string conversion after the field name, but may be I didnt. I still dont understand this. i though `.format`  was just a "smart" way to align and print. Does the .`format` mean that every object being passed into it has its own `.format` that is being invoked?

Comment: @newkid101: yes, formatting is delegated to the `__format__` method on the object.