# .format() padding in Python with None

Tags: python, python-3.x, string.format

I am trying to create consistently formatted log files so they are easier to read. I have long dictionaries and adding padding between my dictionary values would make debugging a lot easier.

Some of my dictionary values == None. When trying to apply .format padding to the None value, python returns an error:

```
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

Notably, when not using padding, the .format() method works just fine.

Below is an example of this error:

```
myList = [
      {'itemNumber': 1, "name":"Bananas","cost":0.99}
      ,{'itemNumber': 2, "name":"Chicken","cost":2.99}
      ,{'itemNumber': 3, "name":"Eggs","cost":4.50}
      ,{'itemNumber': 4, "name":"Mustard","cost":None}
      ,{'itemNumber': 5, "name":"Pretzels","cost":1.99}
      ]

for dict in myList:
    print("Item Number: {0:<4} | Item Name: {1:<10} | Cost: {2:<4}".format(dict['itemNumber'],dict['name'],dict['cost']))
```

Comment: i think this must be a bug? its interesting... what would be the expected behavior here do you think? (surely not the error)

Comment: what should be displayed in place of `None` then? Empty string or `0`? BTW your code prints `None` in string and doesn't raise any exception. (Edit: works in Python 2.7, but raises error in Python 3)

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613676/python-typeerror-non-empty-format-string-passed-to-object-format/29613927#29613927

Comment: Thanks for the link @JoranBeasley -  Adding !s as follows appears to fix the issue: _Cost: {2!s:<4}_