# Python TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__ on example 24 from learn python the hard way book

Tags: python, python-3.x

Got "TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format_"
.

I tried this solution [Python TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170519/python-typeerror-non-empty-format-string-passed-to-object-format), it said to change my format to {!s:s} but it yield another error "tuple index out of range".

This is my code :

```
def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates

start_point = start_point / 10

print("We can also do that this way:")
# Error bellow
print("We'd have {:.0f} beans, {:.0f} jars, and {:.0f} crates."
      .format(secret_formula(start_point)))
```

Got error on last line.

Turn out i need to unpack the return value that i get from calling secret_formula function since it return a tuple.

```
# Unpack tuple by adding asterisk (*) symbol before function call
print("We'd have {:.0f} beans, {:.0f} jars, and {:.0f} crates."
      .format(*secret_formula(start_point)))
```

Comment: That error really misleading.So there no need to unpack for python 2.x ?

Comment: you need to unpack the tuple when passed it to format.

Comment: Yes, i see that now. But in the book they didn't unpack it. And they use python 2.x. So there is no need to unpack for python 2.x ?

Comment: no...its same case for both. if you just pass entire tuple to one format specifiers like `"{}".format(tup) ` result will be same as `print tup` .