# (Coding the Matrix) Python Debug Provided Mat.py: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, matrix

I am learning the Coding the Matrix by myself, and unfortunately, I'm stuck on a provided file, Mat.py. The author of Coding the Matrix provides a file that includes a class for matrix manipulation. But, when I try to use that file as the book instructed, I always run into the error:TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.**format** ... As shown in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPU4x.png)

And the original code for that class is as shown below:

```
def getitem(v,d):
    "Returns the value of entry d in v"
    assert d in v.D
    if d in v.f.keys():
        return v.f[d]
    else:
        return 0

def setitem(v,d,val):
    "Set the element of v with label d to be val"
    assert d in v.D
    v.f[d] = val

def equal(u,v):
    "Returns true iff u is equal to v"
    assert u.D == v.D
    for x in u.D:
        if getitem(u, x) != getitem(v, x):
            return False
    return True

def add(u,v):
    "Returns the sum of the two vectors"
    assert u.D == v.D
    return Vec(u.D, { i:v[i]+u[i] for i in u.f.keys() | v.f.keys() })

def dot(u,v):
    "Returns the dot product of the two vectors"
    assert u.D == v.D
    return sum([getitem(v,d)*getitem(u,d) for d in u.D])

def scalar_mul(v, alpha):
    "Returns the scalar-vector product alpha times v"
    return Vec(v.D, {i:alpha*getitem(v,i) for i in v.D})

def neg(v):
    "Returns the negation of a vector"
    return Vec(v.D, {i:-1*getitem(v,i) for i in v.D})

##### NO NEED TO MODIFY BELOW HERE #####
class Vec:
    """
    A vector has two fields:
    D - the domain (a set)
    f - a dictionary mapping (some) domain elements to field elements
        elements of D not appearing in f are implicitly mapped to zero
    """
    def __init__(self, labels, function):
        self.D = labels
        self.f = function

    __getitem__ = getitem
    __setitem__ = setitem
    __neg__ = neg
    __rmul__ = scalar_mul #if left arg of * is primitive, assume it's a scalar

    def __mul__(self,other):
        #If other is a vector, returns the dot product of self and other
        if isinstance(other, Vec):
            return dot(self,other)
        else:
            return NotImplemented  #  Will cause other.__rmul__(self) to be invoked

    def __truediv__(self,other):  # Scalar division
        return (1/other)*self

    __add__ = add

    def __radd__(self, other):
        "Hack to allow sum(...) to work with vectors"
        if other == 0:
            return self

    def __sub__(a,b):
         "Returns a vector which is the difference of a and b."
         return a+(-b)

    __eq__ = equal

    def __str__(v):
        "pretty-printing"
        try:
            D_list = sorted(v.D)
        except TypeError:
            D_list = sorted(v.D, key=hash)
        numdec = 3
        wd = dict([(k,(1+max(len(str(k)), len('{0:.{1}G}'.format(v[k], numdec))))) if isinstance(v[k], int) or isinstance(v[k], float) else (k,(1+max(len(str(k)), len(str(v[k]))))) for k in D_list])
        # w = 1+max([len(str(k)) for k in D_list]+[len('{0:.{1}G}'.format(value,numdec)) for value in v.f.values()])
        s1 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}}'.format(k,wd[k]) for k in D_list])
        s2 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}.{2}G}'.format(v[k],wd[k],numdec) if isinstance(v[k], int) or isinstance(v[k], float) else '{0:>{1}}'.format(v[k], wd[k]) for k in D_list])
        return "\n" + s1 + "\n" + '-'*sum(wd.values()) +"\n" + s2

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Vec(" + str(self.D) + "," + str(self.f) + ")"

    def copy(self):
        "Don't make a new copy of the domain D"
        return Vec(self.D, self.f.copy())


# from vec import Vec (commented because I pasted the class Vec above)

#Test your Mat class over R and also over GF(2).  The following tests use only R.

def getitem(M, k):
    """
    Returns the value of entry k in M, where k is a 2-tuple
    >>> M = Mat(({1,3,5}, {'a'}), {(1,'a'):4, (5,'a'): 2})
    >>> M[1,'a']
    4
    >>> M[3,'a']
    0
    """
    assert k[0] in M.D[0] and k[1] in M.D[1]
    pass

def equal(A, B):
    """
    Returns true iff A is equal to B.

    Consider using brackets notation A[...] and B[...] in your procedure
    to access entries of the input matrices.  This avoids some sparsity bugs.

    >>> Mat(({'a','b'}, {'A','B'}), {('a','B'):0}) == Mat(({'a','b'}, {'A','B'}), {('b','B'):0})
    True
    >>> A = Mat(({'a','b'}, {'A','B'}), {('a','B'):2, ('b','A'):1})
    >>> B = Mat(({'a','b'}, {'A','B'}), {('a','B'):2, ('b','A'):1, ('b','B'):0})
    >>> C = Mat(({'a','b'}, {'A','B'}), {('a','B'):2, ('b','A'):1, ('b','B'):5})
    >>> A == B
    True
    >>> B == A
    True
    >>> A == C
    False
    >>> C == A
    False
    >>> A == Mat(({'a','b'}, {'A','B'}), {('a','B'):2, ('b','A'):1})
    True
    """
    assert A.D == B.D
    pass

def setitem(M, k, val):
    """
    Set entry k of Mat M to val, where k is a 2-tuple.
    >>> M = Mat(({'a','b','c'}, {5}), {('a', 5):3, ('b', 5):7})
    >>> M['b', 5] = 9
    >>> M['c', 5] = 13
    >>> M == Mat(({'a','b','c'}, {5}), {('a', 5):3, ('b', 5):9, ('c',5):13})
    True

    Make sure your operations work with bizarre and unordered keys.

    >>> N = Mat(({((),), 7}, {True, False}), {})
    >>> N[(7, False)] = 1
    >>> N[(((),), True)] = 2
    >>> N == Mat(({((),), 7}, {True, False}), {(7,False):1, (((),), True):2})
    True
    """
    assert k[0] in M.D[0] and k[1] in M.D[1]
    pass

def add(A, B):
    """
    Return the sum of Mats A and B.

    Consider using brackets notation A[...] or B[...] in your procedure
    to access entries of the input matrices.  This avoids some sparsity bugs.

    >>> A1 = Mat(({3, 6}, {'x','y'}), {(3,'x'):-2, (6,'y'):3})
    >>> A2 = Mat(({3, 6}, {'x','y'}), {(3,'y'):4})
    >>> B = Mat(({3, 6}, {'x','y'}), {(3,'x'):-2, (3,'y'):4, (6,'y'):3})
    >>> A1 + A2 == B
    True
    >>> A2 + A1 == B
    True
    >>> A1 == Mat(({3, 6}, {'x','y'}), {(3,'x'):-2, (6,'y'):3})
    True
    >>> zero = Mat(({3,6}, {'x','y'}), {})
    >>> B + zero == B
    True
    >>> C1 = Mat(({1,3}, {2,4}), {(1,2):2, (3,4):3})
    >>> C2 = Mat(({1,3}, {2,4}), {(1,4):1, (1,2):4})
    >>> D = Mat(({1,3}, {2,4}), {(1,2):6, (1,4):1, (3,4):3})
    >>> C1 + C2 == D
    True
    """
    assert A.D == B.D
    pass

def scalar_mul(M, x):
    """
    Returns the result of scaling M by x.

    >>> M = Mat(({1,3,5}, {2,4}), {(1,2):4, (5,4):2, (3,4):3})
    >>> 0*M == Mat(({1, 3, 5}, {2, 4}), {})
    True
    >>> 1*M == M
    True
    >>> 0.25*M == Mat(({1,3,5}, {2,4}), {(1,2):1.0, (5,4):0.5, (3,4):0.75})
    True
    """
    pass

def transpose(M):
    """
    Returns the matrix that is the transpose of M.

    >>> M = Mat(({0,1}, {0,1}), {(0,1):3, (1,0):2, (1,1):4})
    >>> M.transpose() == Mat(({0,1}, {0,1}), {(0,1):2, (1,0):3, (1,1):4})
    True
    >>> M = Mat(({'x','y','z'}, {2,4}), {('x',4):3, ('x',2):2, ('y',4):4, ('z',4):5})
    >>> Mt = Mat(({2,4}, {'x','y','z'}), {(4,'x'):3, (2,'x'):2, (4,'y'):4, (4,'z'):5})
    >>> M.transpose() == Mt
    True
    """
    pass

def vector_matrix_mul(v, M):
    """
    returns the product of vector v and matrix M

    Consider using brackets notation v[...] in your procedure
    to access entries of the input vector.  This avoids some sparsity bugs.

    >>> v1 = Vec({1, 2, 3}, {1: 1, 2: 8})
    >>> M1 = Mat(({1, 2, 3}, {'a', 'b', 'c'}), {(1, 'b'): 2, (2, 'a'):-1, (3, 'a'): 1, (3, 'c'): 7})
    >>> v1*M1 == Vec({'a', 'b', 'c'},{'a': -8, 'b': 2, 'c': 0})
    True
    >>> v1 == Vec({1, 2, 3}, {1: 1, 2: 8})
    True
    >>> M1 == Mat(({1, 2, 3}, {'a', 'b', 'c'}), {(1, 'b'): 2, (2, 'a'):-1, (3, 'a'): 1, (3, 'c'): 7})
    True
    >>> v2 = Vec({'a','b'}, {})
    >>> M2 = Mat(({'a','b'}, {0, 2, 4, 6, 7}), {})
    >>> v2*M2 == Vec({0, 2, 4, 6, 7},{})
    True
    >>> v3 = Vec({'a','b'},{'a':1,'b':1})
    >>> M3 = Mat(({'a', 'b'}, {0, 1}), {('a', 1): 1, ('b', 1): 1, ('a', 0): 1, ('b', 0): 1})
    >>> v3*M3 == Vec({0, 1},{0: 2, 1: 2})
    True
    """
    assert M.D[0] == v.D
    pass

def matrix_vector_mul(M, v):
    """
    Returns the product of matrix M and vector v.

    Consider using brackets notation v[...] in your procedure
    to access entries of the input vector.  This avoids some sparsity bugs.

    >>> N1 = Mat(({1, 3, 5, 7}, {'a', 'b'}), {(1, 'a'): -1, (1, 'b'): 2, (3, 'a'): 1, (3, 'b'):4, (7, 'a'): 3, (5, 'b'):-1})
    >>> u1 = Vec({'a', 'b'}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
    >>> N1*u1 == Vec({1, 3, 5, 7},{1: 3, 3: 9, 5: -2, 7: 3})
    True
    >>> N1 == Mat(({1, 3, 5, 7}, {'a', 'b'}), {(1, 'a'): -1, (1, 'b'): 2, (3, 'a'): 1, (3, 'b'):4, (7, 'a'): 3, (5, 'b'):-1})
    True
    >>> u1 == Vec({'a', 'b'}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
    True
    >>> N2 = Mat(({('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 8}), {})
    >>> u2 = Vec({1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {})
    >>> N2*u2 == Vec({('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')},{})
    True
    >>> M3 = Mat(({0,1},{'a','b'}),{(0,'a'):1, (0,'b'):1, (1,'a'):1, (1,'b'):1})
    >>> v3 = Vec({'a','b'},{'a':1,'b':1})
    >>> M3*v3 == Vec({0, 1},{0: 2, 1: 2})
    True
    """
    assert M.D[1] == v.D
    pass

def matrix_matrix_mul(A, B):
    """
    Returns the result of the matrix-matrix multiplication, A*B.

    Consider using brackets notation A[...] and B[...] in your procedure
    to access entries of the input matrices.  This avoids some sparsity bugs.

    >>> A = Mat(({0,1,2}, {0,1,2}), {(1,1):4, (0,0):0, (1,2):1, (1,0):5, (0,1):3, (0,2):2})
    >>> B = Mat(({0,1,2}, {0,1,2}), {(1,0):5, (2,1):3, (1,1):2, (2,0):0, (0,0):1, (0,1):4})
    >>> A*B == Mat(({0,1,2}, {0,1,2}), {(0,0):15, (0,1):12, (1,0):25, (1,1):31})
    True
    >>> C = Mat(({0,1,2}, {'a','b'}), {(0,'a'):4, (0,'b'):-3, (1,'a'):1, (2,'a'):1, (2,'b'):-2})
    >>> D = Mat(({'a','b'}, {'x','y'}), {('a','x'):3, ('a','y'):-2, ('b','x'):4, ('b','y'):-1})
    >>> C*D == Mat(({0,1,2}, {'x','y'}), {(0,'y'):-5, (1,'x'):3, (1,'y'):-2, (2,'x'):-5})
    True
    >>> M = Mat(({0, 1}, {'a', 'c', 'b'}), {})
    >>> N = Mat(({'a', 'c', 'b'}, {(1, 1), (2, 2)}), {})
    >>> M*N == Mat(({0,1}, {(1,1), (2,2)}), {})
    True
    >>> E = Mat(({'a','b'},{'A','B'}), {('a','A'):1,('a','B'):2,('b','A'):3,('b','B'):4})
    >>> F = Mat(({'A','B'},{'c','d'}),{('A','d'):5})
    >>> E*F == Mat(({'a', 'b'}, {'d', 'c'}), {('b', 'd'): 15, ('a', 'd'): 5})
    True
    >>> F.transpose()*E.transpose() == Mat(({'d', 'c'}, {'a', 'b'}), {('d', 'b'): 15, ('d', 'a'): 5})
    True
    """
    assert A.D[1] == B.D[0]
    pass

class Mat:
    def __init__(self, labels, function):
        assert isinstance(labels, tuple)
        assert isinstance(labels[0], set) and isinstance(labels[1], set)
        assert isinstance(function, dict)
        self.D = labels
        self.f = function

    __getitem__ = getitem
    __setitem__ = setitem
    transpose = transpose

    def __neg__(self):
        return (-1)*self

    def __mul__(self,other):
        if Mat == type(other):
            return matrix_matrix_mul(self,other)
        elif Vec == type(other):
            return matrix_vector_mul(self,other)
        else:
            return scalar_mul(self,other)
            #this will only be used if other is scalar (or not-supported). mat   and vec both have __mul__ implemented

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        if Vec == type(other):
            return vector_matrix_mul(other, self)
        else:  # Assume scalar
            return scalar_mul(self, other)

    __add__ = add

    def __radd__(self, other):
        "Hack to allow sum(...) to work with matrices"
        if other == 0:
            return self

    def __sub__(a,b):
        return a+(-b)

    __eq__ = equal

    def copy(self):
        return Mat(self.D, self.f.copy())

    def __str__(M, rows=None, cols=None):
        "string representation for print()"
        if rows == None: rows = sorted(M.D[0], key=repr)
        if cols == None: cols = sorted(M.D[1], key=repr)
        separator = ' | '
        numdec = 3
        pre = 1+max([len(str(r)) for r in rows])
        colw = {col:(1+max([len(str(col))] + [len('{0:.{1}G}'.format(M[row,col],numdec)) if isinstance(M[row,col], int) or isinstance(M[row,col], float) else len(str(M[row,col])) for row in rows])) for col in cols}
        s1 = ' '*(1+ pre + len(separator))
        s2 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}}'.format(str(c),colw[c]) for c in cols])
        s3 = ' '*(pre+len(separator)) + '-'*(sum(list(colw.values())) + 1)
        s4 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}} {2}'.format(str(r), pre,separator)+''.join(['{0:>{1}.{2}G}'.format(M[r,c],colw[c],numdec) if isinstance(M[r,c], int) or isinstance(M[r,c], float) else '{0:>{1}}'.format(M[r,c], colw[c]) for c in cols])+'\n' for r in rows])
        return '\n' + s1 + s2 + '\n' + s3 + '\n' + s4

    def pp(self, rows, cols):
        print(self.__str__(rows, cols))

    def __repr__(self):
        "evaluatable representation"
        return "Mat(" + str(self.D) +", " + str(self.f) + ")"

    def __iter__(self):
        raise TypeError('%r object is not iterable' % self.__class__.__name__)

M = Mat(({'a','b'}, {'x','y','z'}), {('a','x'):1, ('a','y'):2, ('a','z'):3, ('b','x'):10, ('b','y'):20, ('b','z'):30})
print(M)
```

I followed Book's instruction to print this matrix, which should look like matrix produced by LaTeX:

```
M = Mat(({'a','b'}, {'x','y','z'}), {('a','x'):1, ('a','y'):2, ('a','z'):3, ('b','x'):10, ('b','y'):20, ('b','z'):30})
print(M)
```

And it returned Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-8c4558fab4a8> in <module>()
----> 1 print(M)

/Users/callforsky/Coding_the_Matrix/mat.py in __str__(M, rows, cols)
259         s2 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}}'.format(str(c),colw[c]) for c in cols])
260         s3 = ' '*(pre+len(separator)) + '-'*(sum(list(colw.values())) + 1)
--> 261         s4 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}} {2}'.format(str(r),      pre,separator)+''.join(['{0:>{1}.{2}G}'.format(M[r,c],colw[c],numdec) if    isinstance(M[r,c], int) or isinstance(M[r,c], float) else '{0:>  {1}}'.format(M[r,c], colw[c]) for c in cols])+'\n' for r in rows])
262         return '\n' + s1 + s2 + '\n' + s3 + '\n' + s4
263 

/Users/callforsky/Coding_the_Matrix/mat.py in <listcomp>(.0)
259         s2 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}}'.format(str(c),colw[c]) for c in cols])
260         s3 = ' '*(pre+len(separator)) + '-'*(sum(list(colw.values())) + 1)
--> 261         s4 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}} {2}'.format(str(r), pre,separator)+''.join(['{0:>{1}.{2}G}'.format(M[r,c],colw[c],numdec) if isinstance(M[r,c], int) or isinstance(M[r,c], float) else '{0:>{1}}'.format(M[r,c], colw[c]) for c in cols])+'\n' for r in rows])
262         return '\n' + s1 + s2 + '\n' + s3 + '\n' + s4
263 

/Users/callforsky/Coding_the_Matrix/mat.py in <listcomp>(.0)
259         s2 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}}'.format(str(c),colw[c]) for c in cols])
260         s3 = ' '*(pre+len(separator)) + '-'*(sum(list(colw.values())) + 1)
--> 261         s4 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}} {2}'.format(str(r), pre,separator)+''.join(['{0:>{1}.{2}G}'.format(M[r,c],colw[c],numdec) if isinstance(M[r,c], int) or isinstance(M[r,c], float) else '{0:>{1}}'.format(M[r,c], colw[c]) for c in cols])+'\n' for r in rows])
262         return '\n' + s1 + s2 + '\n' + s3 + '\n' + s4
263 

TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

I wrote an email to the author for help, but he refused to acknowledge that's the problem of his code. The code is written in Python 3 and I'm using Python 3. I tried to use this code in iPython Notebook, IDLE, Terminal and even Code Runner (yes, I'm using a Mac). But none of them works.

If you could help me out, it would be a big favor! Thanks in advance for any adivce you could provide.

EDIT: I added all codes relevant to this class Mat, should fix all undefined problems.

Comment: Full stackstrace and minimal test case please (in test format, not in an image)

Comment: @Guillaume Edited, thanks so much for the reminder. I am new to this community and still learning.

Comment: Also please check indentation of your class, it is invalid at the moment. And if I indent everything excepted the first line (class declaration), I get a `NameError: name 'getitem' is not defined` on line 9

Comment: @Guillaume Just fixed the indentation and added the possible missing imported library. Does it work now on your side? Please let me know if issue persists and I will fix as soon as possible.

Comment: Same error, getitem is not defined

Comment: @Guillaume I pasted all codes in that file and tested it myself, it should fix the problem you have now. Sorry for delays..!

Comment: `getitem` and `setitem` are defined after they are referenced. You should move them to come before the `Vec` class definition. But there is a further problem: `neg` is undefined.

Comment: @simonb Thanks for looking into this problems at first. I added all relevant codes to this problem, and should fix the undefined problem you had. The order of them are original from the script provided by the book author

Comment: Actually there is still syntax errors with your code (missing `neg`, and functions must be declared before the classes). But I think I get the problem: your `Mat.__getitem__()` method does not work and return `None`, so `M[r,c]` returns `None`, so your `print('{0:>{1}}'.format(M[r,c], colw[c]))` raises a TypeError

Comment: @Guillaume The original files are in author's website: http://resources.codingthematrix.com/ mat.py and vec.py. What I did is combined these two files into one for this thread, but looks like very buggy.. Maybe the author's original script can help debugging? I hope so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the s4 line in 'def __str__' to:

`s4 = ''.join(['{0:>{1}} {2}'.format(str(r), pre,separator)+''.join(['{0:>{1}.{2}G}'.format(M[r,c],colw[c],numdec) if isinstance(M[r,c], int) or isinstance(M[r,c], float) else '{0:>{1}}'.format(str(M[r,c]), colw[c]) for c in cols])+'\n' for r in rows])`

I added a str() to M[4,c] based on conversation in [Python TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170519/python-typeerror-non-empty-format-string-passed-to-object-format)

This gave me the output:
          x    y    z
     ----------------
 a  |  None None None
 b  |  None None None

I then added a return line to 'def getitem':

    `return(M.f[(k[0],k[1])])`

This gives me the output:
        x  y  z
     ----------
 a  |   1  2  3
 b  |  10 20 30

It appears that mat.py is not yet complete. Apparently you need to complete the functions. It was returning None and that went wrong in the __str__ function.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this problem at first. I modified the codes and returned a matrix of 'NONE'. How could I return a matrix defined by M? Which should return some numbers instead of NONE

Comment: @Guillaume code for mat.py and vec.py could be found at http://resources.codingthematrix.com/

Comment: Thank you thank you so much! I finally can continue to study with this course! Thanks again!