# How to format complex number in Python

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers

In my Python script for the line

`result = sp.solve(eqn)`

I get the following output in the format similar to

`result = 0.0100503358535014*I`

I gather this means the solution is a complex number. So in this case it could also be seen as `result = 0.01j`.

I want to add formatting to my code to change `result = 0.0100503358535014*I` to something more like `result = 0.01j`. However I am finding issues trying to do this as I was trying to use `isinstance` to check if `result` was complex

```
if isinstance(result, complex):
        print "Result is complex!"
        ... my code here...
```

However this loop is never entered (i.e `0.0100503358535014*I` isn't classified as complex here).

What way should I write an if statement to check if result is given in the manner `xxxxxxx*I` correctly?

Comment: What is `I` here? Some special constant? If you're not working with `complex`, what *are* you working with?

Comment: I too think that `I` is an actual symbol (it's probably a SymPy library), and not an indication of a complex number.

Comment: What is `type(result)`?

Comment: @Denziloe `type(result) = <class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'> `

Comment: try `if isinstance(result, sympy.core.mul.Mul):`

Comment: @Yang I then get the error `NameError: name 'sympy' is not defined` when I use `if isinstance(result, sp.core.mul.Mul)` Note I used `import sympy as sp` at the beginning of my script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SymPy supports Python's built-in function `complex()`:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x = sympy.sqrt(-2)
>>> x
sqrt(2)*I
>>> complex(x)
1.4142135623730951j
```

There are some examples in http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html

A Python complex number can be formatted similar to a float:

```
>>> format(complex(x), 'e')
'0.000000e+00+1.414214e+00j'
>>> format(complex(x), 'f')
'0.000000+1.414214j'
>>> format(complex(x), 'g')
'0+1.41421j'
```

If you want to format the real and imag parts separately you can do it yourself.

The conversion would raise a TypeError if it can't be done:

```
>>> complex(sympy.Symbol('x'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative which incidentally indicates how to check whether one or both parts of a complex number are available.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('x')
x
>>> expr = (x+0.012345678*I)*(x-0.2346678934)*(x-(3-2.67893455*I))
>>> solve(expr)
[0.234667893400000, -0.012345678*I, 3.0 - 2.67893455*I]
>>> roots = solve(expr)
>>> for root in roots:
...     r, i = root.as_real_imag()
...     '%10.3f %10.3f i' % (r,i)
...     
'     0.235      0.000 i'
'     0.000     -0.012 i'
'     3.000     -2.679 i'
```

You could check the sign of the complex part to decide whether to put a *plus* sign in. I would like to have been able to use the newfangled formatting but fell afoul of the bug which comes with Py3.4+ mentioned in [Python TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170519/python-typeerror-non-empty-format-string-passed-to-object-format) for which I have no remedy.

Answer (score 0):

The following checks whether the sympy object `result` represents a complex number and truncates the float value to `2` decimal points.

```
import sympy as sp

result = 0.0100503358535014*sp.I
print(result.is_complex)
print(sp.N(result,2))
```

> ```
> True
> 0.01*I
> ```

Comment: I have tried this way and it works however if I use an if statement like `if (result.is_complex)` then this return true for both  `type(result) = <class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'>` and `type(result) = <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>` which isn't what I want. How do I get a specific if statement only for when the result has an `*I` part at the end?

Comment: is_complex will return True for a large class of SymPy expressions, including symbolic expressions, and even real numbers. `x.is_complex` just checks if `x` is a complex number.