# Formatting lists of objects in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have read a lot of similar questions related to my question, but I have not seen any specifically for this. 
 I have a list of objects, such as

```
l = ((a, 0.5), (b, 0.75), (c, 0.954367))
```

I want to be able to print out only the numbers, formatted to 5 decimal places. I was not too sure how to go about this, so I started by trying to slice it and then print it as such

```
nums = list(z[1:2] for z in l)    # originally had 'tuple' instead of 'list'
print("numbers: {:.5f}".format(nums))
```

The slicing works, giving me only the numbers, but when I get to the print statement I get an error

```
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

I originally had the slicing to be done as a tuple, but thought that that may have been causing the error so changed it to a list, which did not help.
One answer I read [noted that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24170567) "bytes objects do not have a _ _format__ method of their own, so the default from object is used." and suggested converting it to a string instead - which resulted in the same error.

My question essentially, is there a way to fix this error, or a better way to get the output without slicing/using the method above?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple list comprehension.

```
>>> l = (('a', 0.5), ('b', 0.75), ('c', 0.954367))
>>> ["{:.5f}".format(i[1]) for i in l]
[ '0.50000', '0.75000', '0.95437']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a `float` presentation type, `'f'`, with a list object. That's the cause of the failure.

Supply `print` with a list comprehension of the formatted values which you can unpack and provide as positionals:

```
print("numbers: ", *["{0[0]:.5f}".format(i) for i in nums])
```

This now prints out:

```
numbers:  0.50000 0.75000 0.95437
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
nums = list(z[1] for z in l)
```

z[1:2] essentially gives another list of numbers: `[[0.5],[0.75],[0.954367]]`, which I don't think you require.

Comment: This answer does not address the 5 decimal place formatting constraint.

Comment: this answer was for first line , second line in question was already taking care of 5 decimal point