# non-empty format string passed to object.__format__

Tags: python, object, format

```
print ("Item: {:15} item Cost £{:5.2f} No Items: {:2} Total Cost: £{:5.2f} ".format(a_item, a_cost, a_num, a_totalcost))
```

The error message:

```
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

I have tried but i cannot seem to find how to fix it please help!

Comment: What is the full error message? Is `a_item` a custom type, or a built-in one? Is this python 2 or python 3? In general, can you provide a [Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170519/python-typeerror-non-empty-format-string-passed-to-object-format